# Input field seacrable and select multiple items from list checkbox using angular+typescript mat elements

Tags: angular, typescript, mat

I have a requirement like below :

Input box (text)+ multi-select items with checkboxes at the same place.

I couldn't get any references for these options using angular mat-elements (typescript+angular) version 13.

I tried multiple ways to get it to work but had no luck and there is no such element available through angular mat :(

ref: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html
Here I am looking just like as "Country" input search box. Here I can do both search or select from the options list

Answer (score 0):

the semantic-ui provide the code snippets for what you want.
which is eactly [here](https://codepen.io/alexproca/pen/RaKLXm)

```
<select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
```

Comment: I want to use a similar functionality using angular mat elements. Please help me to get any references for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), it can be useful for your use case

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableRipple>
    <mat-option value="1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```